Publishing new versions of my package without needing to update package.json with each new version. Caret doesn't work. ^0.0.9 doesn't install 0.0.10
"dependencies": {
   "@plugin/my-plugin": "^0.0.9",
}

Above is the version as listed in my package.json. There is also a version 0.0.10. When I do a yarn install, it installs 0.0.9 instead of 0.0.10. Shouldn't the caret mean that 0.0.10 gets installed? I've cleaned the cache, made sure there are no lock files, there are no other dependencies, nothing works.
I don't understand why 0.0.10 isn't being installed. Does it have something to do with it being a version 0 of the plugin?
Specifically what I am trying to do is be able to publish new versions of my package without needing to update package.json each time with a new version. How can this be done?
